# How to use Android Spinner with multiple choice in Fragment of Navigation drawer activity

Tags: android, android-fragments, navigation-drawer

How do I create spinner which allows to choose multiple items, i.e spinner with check boxes? At the same time i need to use this multiple choice spinner inside the fragment of Navigation drawer activity.

Anyone please can clear my doubt with suitable example code.

Thank you in advance!!!

`public class Doctor extends Fragment {
    public Doctor() {
        // Required empty public constructor
    }`

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // Inflate the layout for this fragment
    getActivity().setTitle("Doctor");
    View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_doctor, container, false);
    String [] values =
            {"All Town","Paris","Kodambakkam","Nungambakkam","T.Nagar","Egmore"};
    Spinner spinner = (Spinner) v.findViewById(R.id.town);
    ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this.getActivity(), android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, values);
    adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_dropdown_item_1line);
    spinner.setAdapter(adapter);

    String [] values1 =
            {"Select Doctor","Doctor1","Doctor2","Doctor3","Doctor4"};
    Spinner spinner1 = (Spinner) v.findViewById(R.id.doctor);
    ArrayAdapter<String> adapter1 = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this.getActivity(), android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, values1);
    adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_dropdown_item_1line);
    spinner1.setAdapter(adapter1);

    String [] values2 =
            {"Worked With","Nagaraj","Muthuvel"};
    Spinner spinner2 = (Spinner) v.findViewById(R.id.doctor);
    ArrayAdapter<String> adapter2 = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this.getActivity(), android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, values2);
    adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_dropdown_item_1line);
    spinner2.setAdapter(adapter2);

    return v;
}
public void onViewCreated(View view,@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState){
    super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);

}
```

}

I need to change spinner2 to us multiple choice spinner. I'm extending class from Fragment. So don't know how to handle this multiple choice spinner

Comment: are you using NavigationView in your DrawerLayout

Comment: I not yet got any code regarding this. What ever i try, i getting error message in fragment java.

Comment: Yes i'm using NavigationView in my DrawerLayout.

Comment: https://github.com/GunaseelanArumaikkannu/MultiSpinner

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38559248/unable-to-see-navigation-drawer/38580952#38580952 , i think it may be usefull for you

Comment: refer this link answer for navigation drawer customization http://stackoverflow.com/a/40103274/2784663

Comment: refer this spinner with multi-select checkbox https://trinitytuts.com/tips/multiselect-spinner-item-in-android/

Comment: YLS Thanks. Already i extends Fragment in Doctor and by the way i not able to extend Spinner along with it. How to handle this error???

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> ```
> How do I create spinner which allows to choose multiple items, i.e spinner with check boxes?
> ```

Try using multiselectionspinner. 
https://stackoverflow.com/a/6022474/6616489

And for

> multiple choice spinner inside the fragment of Navigation drawer

Refer https://stackoverflow.com/a/20017862/6616489

Comment: Can you please say how to use "class Doctor extends Fragment,Spinner implements DialogInterface.OnMultiChoiceClickListener"  ??

Getting error on this...

Comment: Also can you give a picture of what you would like to achieve? It would be easier to suggest

Comment: if possible, post your solution

Comment: Please see the answer which i have posted.

Answer (score 0):

```
public class Doctor extends Fragment{

MultiSelectionSpinner spinner2;
FragmentManager fm = getFragmentManager();
public Doctor() {
    // Required empty public constructor
}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // Inflate the layout for this fragment
    getActivity().setTitle("Doctor");
    View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_doctor, container, false);

    String [] values =
            {"All Town","Paris","Kodambakkam","Nungambakkam","T.Nagar","Egmore"};
    Spinner spinner = (Spinner) v.findViewById(R.id.town);
    ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this.getActivity(), android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, values);
    adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_dropdown_item_1line);
    spinner.setAdapter(adapter);

    String [] values1 =
            {"Select Doctor","Doctor1","Doctor2","Doctor3","Doctor4"};
    Spinner spinner1 = (Spinner) v.findViewById(R.id.se_doctor);
    ArrayAdapter<String> adapter1 = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this.getActivity(), android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, values1);
    adapter1.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_dropdown_item_1line);
    spinner1.setAdapter(adapter1);

    String [] values2 =
            {"Worked With","Nagaraj","Muthuvel"};
    // Multi spinner
    spinner2 = (MultiSelectionSpinner)v.findViewById(R.id.work);
    spinner2.setItems(values2);return v;
}}
```

Above code is holding multiple choice spinner (Note: Spinner2)

```
public class MultiSelectionSpinner extends Spinner implements
    OnMultiChoiceClickListener {
String[] _items = null;
boolean[] mSelection = null;

ArrayAdapter<String> simple_adapter;

public MultiSelectionSpinner(Context context) {
    super(context);

    simple_adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(context,
            android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);
    super.setAdapter(simple_adapter);
}

public MultiSelectionSpinner(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs);

    simple_adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(context,
            android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);
    super.setAdapter(simple_adapter);
}

public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which, boolean isChecked) {
    if (mSelection != null && which < mSelection.length) {
        mSelection[which] = isChecked;

        simple_adapter.clear();
        simple_adapter.add(buildSelectedItemString());
    } else {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException(
                "Argument 'which' is out of bounds.");
    }
}

@Override
public boolean performClick() {
    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(getContext());
    builder.setMultiChoiceItems(_items, mSelection, this);
    builder.show();
    return true;
}

@Override
public void setAdapter(SpinnerAdapter adapter) {
    throw new RuntimeException(
            "setAdapter is not supported by MultiSelectSpinner.");
}

public void setItems(String[] items) {
    _items = items;
    mSelection = new boolean[_items.length];
    simple_adapter.clear();
    simple_adapter.add(_items[0]);
    Arrays.fill(mSelection, false);
}

public void setItems(List<String> items) {
    _items = items.toArray(new String[items.size()]);
    mSelection = new boolean[_items.length];
    simple_adapter.clear();
    simple_adapter.add(_items[0]);
    Arrays.fill(mSelection, false);
}

public void setSelection(String[] selection) {
    for (String cell : selection) {
        for (int j = 0; j < _items.length; ++j) {
            if (_items[j].equals(cell)) {
                mSelection[j] = true;
            }
        }
    }
}

public void setSelection(List<String> selection) {
    for (int i = 0; i < mSelection.length; i++) {
        mSelection[i] = false;
    }
    for (String sel : selection) {
        for (int j = 0; j < _items.length; ++j) {
            if (_items[j].equals(sel)) {
                mSelection[j] = true;
            }
        }
    }
    simple_adapter.clear();
    simple_adapter.add(buildSelectedItemString());
}

public void setSelection(int index) {
    for (int i = 0; i < mSelection.length; i++) {
        mSelection[i] = false;
    }
    if (index >= 0 && index < mSelection.length) {
        mSelection[index] = true;
    } else {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("Index " + index
                + " is out of bounds.");
    }
    simple_adapter.clear();
    simple_adapter.add(buildSelectedItemString());
}

public void setSelection(int[] selectedIndicies) {
    for (int i = 0; i < mSelection.length; i++) {
        mSelection[i] = false;
    }
    for (int index : selectedIndicies) {
        if (index >= 0 && index < mSelection.length) {
            mSelection[index] = true;
        } else {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Index " + index
                    + " is out of bounds.");
        }
    }
    simple_adapter.clear();
    simple_adapter.add(buildSelectedItemString());
}

public List<String> getSelectedStrings() {
    List<String> selection = new LinkedList<String>();
    for (int i = 0; i < _items.length; ++i) {
        if (mSelection[i]) {
            selection.add(_items[i]);
        }
    }
    return selection;
}

public List<Integer> getSelectedIndicies() {
    List<Integer> selection = new LinkedList<Integer>();
    for (int i = 0; i < _items.length; ++i) {
        if (mSelection[i]) {
            selection.add(i);
        }
    }
    return selection;
}

private String buildSelectedItemString() {
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    boolean foundOne = false;

    for (int i = 0; i < _items.length; ++i) {
        if (mSelection[i]) {
            if (foundOne) {
                sb.append(", ");
            }
            foundOne = true;

            sb.append(_items[i]);
        }
    }
    return sb.toString();
}

public String getSelectedItemsAsString() {
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    boolean foundOne = false;

    for (int i = 0; i < _items.length; ++i) {
        if (mSelection[i]) {
            if (foundOne) {
                sb.append(", ");
            }
            foundOne = true;
            sb.append(_items[i]);
        }
    }
    return sb.toString();
}}
```

Above code is for creating Multi Selection Spinner which is being called from spinner2.

Please go through the code. If any doubt please comment here, let me try to clear your doubt.